# Distributing Android app (APK) using micro USB key

Tags: android, installation, apk, usb-drive

As part of a marketing campaign, we are planning to give out free USB drives (with both Standard and Micro plugs on either end).

I'm wondering if there is a way to distribute our App this way:
1. User plugs in the USB key into the phone
2. Some prompt automatically pops up asking user if he/she allows the installation of the APK on the USB key

Is this doable?